# Ice cream technique - what should I mix into what?

Tags: ice-cream

I have a homemade non-dairy ice cream recipe that involves a snow of egg whites and sugars, whip, and the egg yolks. At this point, the recipe says "mix together slowly with yolks". In which order should I mix the 3 components? I assume that I should be folding the egg whites into the whip... What is the "correct" way to do this? (That will ensure that the yolks don't sink to the bottom in the freezer :) )

Comment: When you say whip what do you mean? Cool whip?

Comment: @GdB- Miracle whip.

Comment: What does it say right before that step? "mix together slowly with yolks" implies that it just said what you should be mixing with the yolks.

Comment: Most ice cream recipes call for only egg yolks. In my experience including the whites results in very strange freezing. I've ended up with solid blocks of frozen flavored milk by including whites. That said, it looks like some recipes on the internet do use the whole egg.

Comment: @gdb - richwhip that has been whipped :)

Comment: @jefromi - it was a recipe that was copied down in a rush. It's not so correct. I was just wondering what would be the best technique

Answer (score 1):

I usually beat two whole eggs with an electric mixer and then slowly mix the sugar into the eggs before adding the cream, milk, and flavoring. I've never had a problem with the egg whites that way. In your case I'd do the same but treat the beaten egg whites and Rich Whip as the "additional dairy" to be added after the egg yolks and sugar are slowly mixed together.

I've never actually tried whipping egg whites for an ice cream recipe -- my guess is that any air it contributed would be immediately removed once the ice cream machine started turning. It's the ice cream machine's job to incorporate air into the mix anyway. But it might be worth a try.